# mostrar sumatoria de columnas mysql y sus columnas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

he estado googleando y no termino de entender como mostrar la sumatoria de una columna y mostrar los valores de las columnas que sumo.

por ejemplo:

Tabla
Usuarios
id,
nombre,
valor1
valor2

me gustaria mostrar la sumatoria de los valores 1 pero me gustaria que me mostrara que valores se han sumado.

siguiendo el ejemplo

```
1,pedro,2,2
2,pablo,4,2
3,pedro,3,2
```

se que sacar la sumatoria se hace haciendo un 
SELECT id, nombre, SUM(valor1) as sumavalor1

pero esto me demanda un solo ROW con la sumatoria y un solo nombre

quisiera que me mostrara algo asi:

```
1,pedro,2,2
3,pedro,3,2
sumavalor1=5
```

Saludos!
Espero que se entienda lo que digo.

PD: Quiero mostrar historial de pago de una persona y el total de pagos y que el cliente pueda ver la fecha y el pago que realizo antes de la sumatoria de esos pagos.
PD: En la misma tabla hay mas de 1 persoona con nombres distintos.

> Cita en bloque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok amigo me doy cuenta por medio de sus tag que esta trabajando aparte de mysql como motor de base de datos php como lenguaje y javascript entonces esto puede facilitar algo con lo que dices

primero que todo aveces queremos hacer todo en una consulta super complicada y poco sostenible entonces si lo que quieres hacer es un select con todo el historial de compra de un cliente pues hazlo por aparte

```
select * from Usuarios where id = @idUsuario
```

puedes despues almacenar eso en un arraylist o dibujarlo de un solo en html
ahora para el total has otra consulta

```
select SUM(valor1) as sumavalor1 from Usuarios where id = @idUsuarios
```

de esta forma es facil de leer y mantener
tambien puedes hacer solo la primera consulta y la sumatoria por php,

PD: si tenias que filtrar la información haces un select antes y lo almacenas en unas variables en php, recuerda que estas usando un conjunto de herramientas que te pueden facilitar la vida, no te mates solo usando sql Salufos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario Pablo Puente :) gracias por tu ayuda amigo!